# How to use Regex to detect a text with special character in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

In Ruby, i would like to detect keywords like 'feed' or 'f' followed by either whitespaces or special characters.

I did something like :

```
if m = (/\A(feedback|feed|f)\s*([A-Za-z0-9_#;\s\?@&'"()]*)\z/i.match(command))
  puts m[2]
end
```

However, this does not work as expected. What is the best Regex to match these keywords?

Comment: What does not work? Please provide examples where it does not work. What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Also, a concrete example of what you expect to happen would be helpful.

Comment: i'm expecting m[2] to have full message after feed, like if put 'feed some message with special@ charecter"s', then expecting m[2] to be -> feed some message with special@ charecter"s

Comment: Well, so you basically want to match *anything* after the keyword *including* the keyword?

Comment: discluding the keyword, sorry, previously I made a mistake, i'm expecting m[2] to return -> some message with special@ charecter"s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to match anything after the keyword:

```
/\A(feedback|feed|f)(.*)\z/
```

Answer (score 2):

My sugesstion

```
/\Af(eed(back)?)?\W+\z/
```